# Does git-http-backend compress/uncompress the objects it sends?

Tags: git

It's not entirely clear to me how git-http-backend un/compresses the objects it sends to the client.  After I see some messages saying that it did find and compress several objects on the server, on the client side, I see the objects appear almost one by one in the directory structure you'd expect.

I'm assuming it has GZIP'd each object on the server side for over-the-wire efficiency and then as it receives the objects and builds the repo on the client size it unzips each object right away.  Is that correct?  I guess I was expecting one big zip file sent and unzipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, git-http-backend creates a custom packfile based on what objects are needed and sends it to the client. And the objects are zlib compressed.

[image]

From: http://progit.org/2010/03/04/smart-http.html

Comment: Ok, then what happens is the packfile delivered to the client is reconstituted into the git repo (i.e., the actual source files) requiring no further network operations?

Comment: Did some more testing and confirmed it does cease any further network operations after pulling the packfile, but unpacking that packfile takes twice as long as downloading it and this is on SSD!

Comment: @occasl - Git is optimized at the filesystem level, and being a DVCS, I believe keeping network usage to minimum would have been priority.